# ggplot density plot for multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

Using R ggplot to plot density plot for multiple plot.

Using the following data.frame:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  sex=factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=5)),
  weight=round(c(rnorm(5, mean=0, sd=0),
                 rnorm(5, mean=2, sd=5)))
)
```

Let's first plot only the female group:

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot(df %>% filter(sex=="F"), aes(x=weight, color=sex)) + geom_density()
```

Women only density plot

[image]

But, if we try to plot both men and women:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=weight, color=sex)) + geom_density()
```

density plot for both women and men

[image]

We get a completely different density plot for the women

I assumed that the density is being calculated per population. So, adding a different population (men in this case) shouldn't change the women density.

Answer (score 3):

All the women have a weight of 0, so the `from` and `to` in `density()` are both 0, which is why you get a vertical line. When the men are added, you get a different `from` and `to` (-10 and 7, the range of `weight` now), and then it does a density estimation with a bandwidth determined by the `nrd0` algorithm. (See `?bw.nrd0`; in this case it's about 4 for men and 0.65 for women.) The smoothing (gaussian by default) creates the peaked shape.

To get a better idea of what's going on, try some other arguments for the parameters of `density()`, e.g.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=weight, color=sex)) + geom_density(kernel = 'triangular', bw = 0.5)
```

[image: triangular with longer bandwidth]

Comment: I assumed that the density is being calculated per population. So, adding a different population (men in this case) wouldn't change the women density.

Comment: Groups are separate, but share some parameters like `from` and `to` that are changed by adding a group.

Comment: Can I "force" geom_density to plot the first plot above for women?

Comment: You could write your own stat, but you don't want to; it's easier to calculate the densities separately before plotting.